# how to mock long json response via dojo registry?

Tags: dojo, mocking

I'm trying to follow [this article](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2014/07/14/mocking-data-with-intern/) to mock some response.
I'm porting mocked data from existing mocking service. There are some really long json responses, such as:

> "{\"Layout\":{\"Id\":\
>   .......
>   "Image1\":\"test.png\",\"Image2\":\"\",\"multi\":[\"test1\",\"test2\",\"test3\"]}}"

There are a few hundred lines in the "......". Is there a easy way of doing this? Can I load the response from a file when I register the mock response?

Comment: You can have a look at a blog by 'Dimitri M" over [here](http://g00glen00b.be/dojo-mobile-model/) who has used **JSON file** to create a mock store. Hope it helps.

Comment: @frank, I need to mock a web service end point as opposed to a store. But thanks for the link, it's an interesting blog.

Answer (score 0):

It should be trivial to set up a mock provider to respond with data from separate local static files.  Just return the result of sending an XHR (with `dojo/request/xhr`) to the desired static resource.

The following example assumes you have a static JSON resource in a path relative to your mock provider module:

```
define([
    'require',
    'dojo/request/registry',
    'dojo/request/xhr'
], function (require, registry, xhr) {
    registry.register('/service', function (url, options) {
        // Presuming you're already passing handleAs: 'json' in options anyway,
        // you can just pass options to the xhr call as-is.
        return xhr(require.toUrl('./data/sample.json'), options);
    });
    ...
    return registry;
});
```